# jspeex decoder not producing the correct output

Tags: audio, jspeex

I am using JSpeex api for decoding rtmp audio stream into wave file and using the same stream to save speex encoded audio to flv file.

I found that there are differences in both the audio.

1. Time length of both audio file is different. FLV shows the original timing while wave file time is always less than the FLV file.
2. The quality of FLV is better that wave file.
3. The voice does not match to speaker in wave file, but FLV seems to be perfect.

Can somebody guide me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSpeex](http://jspeex.sourceforge.net/) is based on the 1.0.3. version of Speex, which was released in 2003. There have been several new versions since then, the most recent being [1.2rc1](http://www.speex.org/news/) (released in 2008). Is it possible that your audio has been encoded in a newer version of Speex than 1.0.3?

Comment: i am trying to decode the audio on wowza server, transmitted from the flex recorder to wowza server. I want the audio in PCM SIGNED format on wowza server. Can you guide me to find how to decode it in required format?

Comment: You could save the speex data to a file and then use a command line tool like speexdec.exe that is part of speex, or ffmpeg to convert to WAV.

Comment: 1. Is there a Java-based implementation of Speex decoder that tracks the Speex development more closely?
2. What version of Speex encoder is used in Flash Player (v10.x)

Comment: 1. I'm afraid I don't know of one

Comment: 2. I don't know, but since the latest Speex is a couple of years old it would be a reasonable guess to assume they are running with the latest (1.2rc1), or at least the latest non-beta release - 1.1.12.